# CakePHP Auth Component not hashing password at login

Tags: cakephp, passwords, hash, authentication

I'm not really sure what's going on here. This is what I have in my app_controller.php:

```
<?php

class AppController extends Controller {

var $components = array('Auth');
var $helpers = array('Form', 'Session');

function beforeFilter() {

    $this->Auth->allow('register');
    $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.activated' => true);
    $this->Auth->loginError = "<span style=\"color:#FF0000\">Wrong username or password</span>";
    $this->Auth->fields = array(            
        'username' => 'username',             
        'password' => 'password'
    );
    }
}

?>
```

and my users_controller.php:

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Users';
var $components = array('Auth');
var $helpers = array('Form', 'Session');

function index() {



}

function login() {

    $this->set('title_for_layout', "Welcome to .com!");
    $this->layout = 'user_functions';

}

function logout() {

    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());

}

function register(){

    $this->set('title_for_layout', "Register Here!");
    $this->layout = 'user_functions';
    $date = date('Y');

    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $user_check = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('username' => $this->data['User']['username'])));
        $email_check = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('e-mail' => $this->data['User']['e-mail'])));
        if (empty($user_check)) {
            if(empty($email_check)){
                if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                    $uuid_string = $this->data['User']['activation_hash'];
                    $email = //email
                    $to = $this->data['User']['e-mail'];
                    $subject = 'Welcome to .com!';
                    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= 'From: '';

                    if (mail($to, $subject, $email, $headers)) {
                        $this->redirect('/');
                    }
                } else {
                    //$this->Session->setFlash('<p class="register_flash">Something went wrong. Please try again.</p>', 'flash_registration');
                    //$this->flash('', '/');
                }
            } else {

                //email exists

            }
        } else {

            //username exists

        }
    }   
}
}





?>
```

and here's my view:

```
<div id="login">
<p>Please log in! <a id="register" href="register" alt="Register">Register</a></p>
<hr class="login"/>
<?php    
    echo $this->Session->flash('auth');    
    echo $this->Form->create('User');    
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo "<hr class=\"login\"/>";
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
    echo $this->Session->flash('flash_registration');
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->data); echo "</pre>";
?>

</div>
```

Basically, when I try to login using my login form, even if I use the password that I used when I registered, it says that the username or password is incorrect. However, when I changed the password stored in the database to 'password' in plain text, and tried logging in with that, it worked! I have no idea why this is happening. I also echoed out $this->data on the login view, and the username is right, but the password is empty. From what I can see , the password is just not hashing.

Comment: you didnt mention your cake version - is it 1.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

I think you mean mask, not hash, the password at input time.  This should be simple...

```
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password'));
```

Comment: I'm using CakePHP 1.3. Is it supposed to automatically hash the password when they enter it at the login screen? That's where the issue is. It's entering the hashed password into the database perfectly. It's just not hashing the password the person enters when trying to log in. Is there a way to hash the password that the person enters before it matches it against the database?

Comment: See if the change to my answer helps.

Comment: It's still not working. It's not hashing the password when they enter it at login. When I echo out $this->data, the password field is empty.

Comment: I think what's happening is that you are submitting the form which sends data to the login() function in your controller.  There, you don't do anything with the data and I believe the auth component removes password for security reasons.  In login(), do a print_r of your data and see what is there after you submit the form (so you will need to wrap it in a condition).